# Angular12 - Issues in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular12

I am trying this sample bootstrap dropdown code. There is no error but my dropdown is not working
I have installed jquery-popper, jquery and bootstrap 5

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
expanded="false">
Dropdown button
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
```

This is how my angular.json looks like

```
`        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple- 
          amber.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss"

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
        ]`
```

I have also included "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js", in script array and tried but nothing happens. Am I missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of bootstrap are you using? In case you are using v5, you should not import jQuery, as Bootstrap dropped jQuery in its latest version.

> Our latest release, Bootstrap 5, focuses on improving v4’s codebase with as few major breaking changes as possible. We improved existing features and components, removed support for older browsers, dropped jQuery for regular JavaScript, and embraced more future-friendly technologies like CSS custom properties as part of our tooling.

(Taken from the [Bootstrap About Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/about/overview/))

For some components (e.g. Popovers, Tooltips), you will need Popper.js. Make sure to include it by either passing both Bootstrap and Popper.js into the scripts section or just include the complete Bootstrap bundle which contains Popper.js like so:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
  // other script files ...
],
```

You can also use the minified version of the bundle (`[...].bundle.min.js`)